# Cascading Combo Boxes in the Filter row of a DevExpress Aspx Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress

Throughout my ASP.net application I employee the 'cascading combo boxes' technique as depicted below.

[image]

For anyone not familiar with the term, cascading combo boxes is a technique where the datasource of one combo box is bound to the datasource of another.  For example in the image above, the 'Sport' combobox choices changes based on the input of the 'Sport Category' combo box likewise, the Keyword combobox choices change based on what the user selects in the 'Sport combo box'.

What I want to know is if there is any way to acomplish this same technique in the filter rows of the DevExpress suite's AspxGridview contorl and if so can anyone show or point me to some examples of how to acomplish this.

Comment: Do you want to add filter rows containing dropdown list inside header column of Gridview?

Comment: What kind of datasource are you using? And have you tried Control Prameters?  If so what is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below links show the same:

[E112- Change the filter combobox list values based on the value another filter combobox](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E112.aspx)

[ASPxGridView cascading ComboBox in the Filter Row](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q155269.aspx?searchtext=cascading%20combobox%20in%20filter%20row)